# td-agent does not validate google cloud service account credentials

Tags: gcloud, fluentd, td-agent

Trying to configure fluentd output with td-agent and the fluent-google-cloud plugin. The plugin and all dependencies are loaded but fluentd is not outputting to google cloud logging and the td-agent log states `error="Unable to read the credential file specified by GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: file /home/$(whoami)/.config/gcloud/service_account_credentials.json does not exist"`.
However when I go to the file path, the file does exist and the $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS variable is set to the file path as well.What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption that the error and you are both correct, I suspect (!) that you're using your user account ( == `whoami`) and finding `/home/$(whoami)/.config/gcloud` while the agent is running (under `systemctl`?) as root and **not** finding the credentials file there (perhaps `/root/.config/gcloud`.

It would be helpful if you included more details as to what you've done in order that we can better understand the issue.

Comment: The path of the credentials file is /home/$(whoami)/.config/gcloud and td-agent is running under systemctl. But that should not matter right?

Comment: It's unclear how you're running the agent because you do not explain in your question. If the agent is running under `systemctl` then it's running as the root account not `$(whoami)` and so it would need to look for the file in a different place. If the agent is running on e.g. a Compute Engine VM, you should not encounter the issue because Application Default Credentials will obtain the VM's credentials automagically for you.

Comment: Where could the credentials be stored then and accessed? Since the agent is running as root, shouldn't it be able to look in any home folder? It not running on Compute Engine VM, this is on premise machine.

Comment: Please see my answer. It's possibly looking in `/root/.config/gcloud`

Comment: I tried that already and put the credentials in root but it still just says `Unable to read the credential file specified by GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: file /root/.config/gcloud/service_account_credentials.json does not exist"`.

Comment: Hmmm.... It would be helpful, if you update the question with more details about how you're running the agent. Please include the result (please redact the values) from `cat /root/.config/gcloud/service_account_credentials.json`

Comment: So it works now as I have chmod 777 the service_account_credentials.json file and the service starts, but now it says `Failed to access metadata service:  error_class=Net::OpenTimeout error="execution expired"`. Any ideas on thi?s

Comment: You won't be able to access Metadata service off-GCP. You'll need to run on Compute Engine to be able to access Metadata service

Comment: Why is that, why can't an on premise machine use a metadata service?

Comment: We've strayed from your original question. Please consider marking my answer as the answer to your question and asking further follow-up questions as new questions. The metadata service is *only* available to Compute Engine VMs. See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata/overview Generally (!?) Cloud Logging is only accessible to resources running on GCP and, I suspect, the authors of `td-agent` did not anticipate folks trying to run it on-premises|off-GCP. It needn't be a requirement but evidently it is.